# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el cast a int() en Perl?

Tags: perl, casting, cast

Estoy intentando de convertir los decimales a entero para después obtener la fracción irreducible, para esto hago lo siguiente:

```
my $input = <STDIN>;
my $denominador = 1;
chomp($input);
until ($input == int($input)){
    $input *= 10;
    $denom *= 10};
```

`print("Num: ", int($input), " Denom: ", $denom);`

Probando esto me funciona perfecto cuando introduzco el número: 0.2324
obtengo como resultado:

```
Decimal: 0.2324 
2.324 Int input: 2
23.24 Int input: 23
232.4 Int input: 232
2324 Int input: 2324
Num: 2324 Denom: 10000
```

Pero cuando introduzco:0.444 ó .376 y sus múltiplos obtengo un mal funcionamiento:

```
Decimal: 0.444
4.44 Int input: 4
44.4 Int input: 44
**444 Int input: 444**
4440 Int input: 4440
44400 Int input: 44400
444000 Int input: 444000
4440000 Int input: 4440000
44400000 Int input: 44400000
444000000 Int input: 444000000
```

Ésas son impresiones de la comparación del until, según esto no son iguales esos números. Ahora un print con el 0.376:

```
Decimal: **0.376**
3.76 Int input: 3
37.6 Int input: 37
**376 Int input: 375**
**3760 Int input: 3759**
37600 Int input: 37599
376000 Int input: 375999
3760000 Int input: 3759999
37600000 Int input: 37599999
376000000 Int input: 375999999
3760000000 Int input: 3759999999
37600000000 Int input: 37599999999
376000000000 Int input: 375999999999
3760000000000 Int input: 3759999999999
37600000000000 Int input: 37599999999999
376000000000000 Int input: 375999999999999
3.76e+15 Int input: 3759999999999999
3.76e+16 Int input: 37599999999999992
**Num: 37599999999999992 Denom: 100000000000000000**
```

Cuando el Num: 376 Denom: 1000

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregir ese problema?¿Es debido al casting del int()?

Saludos

Comment: FYI: 0.2324 es 581/2500, 0.444 es 111/250, y 0.376 es 47/125. Puede que te interese usar el modulo `Math::BigRat`

Comment: Muchas gracias! voy a verificar el módulo. Lo que sí buscaba es realizar yo todo el procesamiento, y me funciona bien con muchos números excepto con algunos, como los que pongo de ejemplo y me gustaría saber a qué se deba que no funcione correctamente. Nuevamente te agradezco [ninjalj] ya que no conocía ese módulo y ahora tengo conocimiento de él! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay ciertos valores de punto flotante cuya representación en binario (dentro de la máquina virtual Perl, y al igual que el resto de lenguajes) no siempre es perfecta. Siempre hay errores en los últimos decimales, que provoca en ocasiones, bucles infinitos o errores de redondeo.

El cómo solucionarlo. Ya te han comentado usar el módulo Math::BigRat, que sirve para estos casos en los que necesitamos una precisión más alta.

Otra opción... como Perl maneja muy bien las cadenas de texto, y pasar de cadena a número es muy sencillo, podemos usar el truco de mirar por el punto decimal '.' (usando rindex()) para saber qué posición ocupa. De ahí sacamos el denominador. Y el numerador es eliminar ese punto (con substr(), por ejemplo) o simplemente haciendo una multiplicación. Ejemplo:

```perl
$x = 10.376;
$pos_p = rindex $x, ".";
$denominador = ($pos_p < 0) ? 1 : 10 ** ( length($x) - $pos_p - 1 );
$numerador = $x * $denominador;
print "[$numerador/$denominador]\n";
```